# Lowest digit addition generator

Tags: code-golf, sequence

A *digit addition generator* of an integer `n` is any integer `x` that satisfy the equation `x + s(x) = n`, with `s(x)` being the sum of the digits of `x`. (We will work under base 10 for convenience.)

For example, a digit addition generator for `29` would be `19`, because `19 + (1 + 9) = 29`. Some numbers have more than one generator. An example might be `216`, which has generators of `198` and `207`.

Your objective is to generate the sequence `a_n` where `a_i` is the **lowest** digit addition generator of every non-negative integer `i`, and *anything other than a non-negative integer* if there is none for `i`.
The non-negative terms in your result should match the sequence [A096234](https://oeis.org/A096234). You may find [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.14365.pdf) related to the challenge.

Fewest bytes win; standard rules apply.

Comment: If there is no solution, is it acceptable to loop forever without output, or do we need to terminate?

Comment: @xnor That's okay.

Comment: Presumably the expected output for `0` is `0`?

Comment: @Shaggy Yes. `0 + (0)` is indeed `0`

Comment: Just making sure that `x<=n` and not just `x<n`. Perhaps you could add `n=0` to the challenge as a test case, along with a few others, as a few of us did get tripped up by it.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ý.ΔDªOQ
```

Outputs `-1` if there is no result.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Fy9c1NcDq3yD/z/38gSAA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWhlf8Pz9U7N8Xl0Cr/Q@sC/9fq/I82stQxMjTTMdAxBCEgNjLWsbQwN9Mx1AHKgMQsdAwtLWIB).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ý        # Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input-integer]
 .Δ      # Find the first value of this list that's truthy for, or -1 if none are:
   D     #  Duplicate the current value
    ª    #  Convert the first value to a list of digits,
         #  and append the duplicated number to this list
     O   #  Sum the list together
      Q  #  Check whether it's equal to the (implicit) input-integer
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: That was quick!

Comment: @TomEpsilon Could have been quicker if I saw the challenge 10 minutes earlier. ;) Nice first challenge btw, and welcome to CGCC!

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `gM`, 28 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 3.5 bytes

```
'∑+?=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJnPU0iLCIiLCIn4oiRKz89IiwiIiwiMCJd)

Outputs an empty list for no result. I think (spoiler I did) I ninja'd someone in the process of writing this lol.

### Explained

```
'∑+?=
'      # filter the range [0, n] by:
 ∑+    #   sum of digits + x
   ?=  #   equals input? 
# g flag prints minimum.
```

Comment: Lol, I've been ninja'd

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs `-1` for no result.

```
ôÈ+ìxÃbU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9Mgr7HjDYlU&input=Mjk)

(Eventually) outputs `undefined` for no result.

```
@¶X+ìx}a
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QLZYK%2bx4fWE&input=Mjk)

```
ôÈ+ìxÃbU     :Implicit input of integer U
ô            :Range [0,U]
 È           :Pass each through the following function
  +          :  Add
   ì         :  Convert to digit array
    x        :  Reduce by addition
     Ã       :End function
      bU     :First 0-based index of U
```

```
@¶X+ìx}a     :Implicit input of integer U
@            :Function taking an integer X as argument
 ¶           :  Test U for equality with
  X+         :    Add to X
    ì        :      Convert X to digit array
     x       :      Reduce by addition
      }      :End function
       a     :Get the first integer >=0 that returns true
```

Comment: Yup, your second version is what I came up with as well. (This is Jacob, I changed my username)

Comment: [6 bytes `+ìx ¥N` `-æ`](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LeY&code=K%2bx4IKVO&input=MjE2)

Comment: Came up with the exact same while I was out to lunch, @noodleman :) Do you want to run with it before I edit it into mine?

Comment: Scratch that, @noodleman; it [fails for `0`](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LeY&code=K%2bx4IKVO&input=MA).

Comment: I think I can add the `x` flag, which does nothing for regular outputs and throws an error for `undefined`, i.e. empty output, and `"" == 0`. I'm going to post my version now.

Answer (score 4):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 44 bytes

```
f(n,i)=if(i>n,x,i+sumdigits(i)-n,f(n,i+1),i)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN3XSNPJ0MjVtM9M0Mu3ydCp0MrWLS3NTMtMzS4o1MjV18yAKtA01gaqgelTT8os08hRsFQx0FAwNgERBUWZeCVBESUHXDkgAdWhqQhXDLAIA)

Returns `x` when there is no solution.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 21 bytes

Anoymous tacit prefix function. Requires 0-indexing (`⎕IO←0`).

```apl
⍸⊢<\⍤=0,⍨⍳+1⊥¨⍎¨∘⍕¨∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/x/17njUtcgm5lHvElsDnUe9Kx71btY2fNS19BCQ1QckOmY86p0KpTf/TwNqAoo/6mp@1LvmUe@WQ@uNH7VNBBoXHOQMJEM8PIP/azzqXaWTdmiFJlCDoYERAA)

`⍸` where do we find that

`⊢` the argument

`<\` is the first (lit. cum. right-ass. less red.)

`⍤` that:

`=` equals

`0,⍨` zero appended to

`⍳` the range

`+` plus

`1⊥` the sum (lit. base-1 eval.)

`¨` of each of

`⍎` the evaluation

`¨` of each

`⍤` of:

`⍕` the stringification

`¨` of each

`⍤` of:

`⍳` the range

Comment: I’m sorry, but what does “ lit. cum. right-ass. less red.” mean?

Comment: @TomEpsilon **lit**erally **cum**ulative **right-ass**ociative **less red**uction

Answer (score 4):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 58 bytes

*loops forever if there's no solution*

```c
d,s;f(*i,n){for(*i=s=0;n-s;)for(s=d=++*i;d;d/=10)s+=d%10;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7BTsMwEETP8VesilLZjQMOB0S1OF/CJfLGraV0g@K0HKr8OmYLt5nZN6MNbZgGPpVCNmPUh2TZ3OO8iPLZO@Q2o3n47Mk3zSEhIb34zpnceKo7h1t5ShymK43wkVdK8/O5Vyrxqi5DYn2bExl1V5UkwBaWcUWlqu9zmkbQOQwc9a6mnYU9G@jBGRC4inovpAU2KO5rkfYfB20PNX2y8P9jj/smgyKvC4NDtZXX7u0nxGk45dLKSz68H38B)

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 70 bytes

For comparison, this returns negative values when there's no solution.

```c
g,o,l;f(*i,n){for(*i=g=-n;g++;*i=n+l?*i:-g)for(l=o=g;o;o/=10)l+=o%10;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BTgMxDETPm6@wihYlTQK7IKGCm/IjXFZJk0YKTrXdcqn21wmuxMljz/hpvPVlotRaMtUUjHKbDalbrDMrl5wlTFoja9Llc5s/bFJ3s7jqElasz24cVNGu9uOAa3vI5Ms1HGF/WUKuT6eDEJkW8T1lkj81ByVuouMLkIH5uKAQHfNAEjgYEAj28MpTa1LAyS7KR44ZIIW8nWd@jXLTB7AH6MMXbcw/6e6vTGN5nYlZYm0v49uvj2VKl2a5j/O79z8)

Answer (score 4):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>71</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>66</s></sup> 64 bytes

```cpp
[](int&n){for(int m=n,d=n=0,t;m-d;)for(d=t=++n;t;t/=10)d+=t%10;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VdHRbpswFAbg@zyFxbQJCmhgm3StcW6mPUWSC2RMhtqYCMwULcqrj/02oKZIcHx8vmNhW10u6UmpqRptRxo57Y9ha@w3E92arndDcpYmqaWRWWLFOa1F5Aq1tDKOjbDCfpd5FtWxtF/zTNwnsfnSGvU@1pqUbTfYXlfn3cPcH61s1@82fumqNWF02xA8g61fX@diidqO6OsFma6JJLcsIWmekHwOdA5sDnwOBcpgWwRkzwhgPxDAXhAWlsNRuByQuhySQuagFDSHpYulsAyWwjKXwzJYCstgKSxbLIPlsAyWuxyWwzJYDstg@WI5bAHLYQuXwxawHLaA5bDFui3YLWwBu3U57JbehT8z1ZnBEvW76p/w1epN9/ujO6/gcP1FD9eXn3iLICGPOQuWbtwj8Tfcmlpf0ZaJZVjOtzG0f3W4XkMkSBz7ckTmG3OPa7do9QXxaVpjem3e@/rxATQkBJDYY@S2YVsz6o9yE9ro82oDVrMfU/7/VDdaUpbrT5ckIOkOH4yGOfXj9WS0lMPRzx9MMC9139ynf6p5r07DlKZYVJ7MGMe0@g8)

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to [c--](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112488/c)!!!*

Comment: @c-- Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: @c-- Very good - thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>89</s> <s>53</s> <s>49</s> 44 bytes

```
#&@@Pick[r=Range@#,r+Tr/@IntegerDigits@r,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X1nNwSEgMzk7usg2KDEvPdVBWadIO6RI38EzryQ1PbXIJTM9s6TYoUhHOVbtv39aWrRbaV5ySWZ@npVVcU5@SV4sV0BRZl5JdJqCvoMCxARjA4PY/wA)

Thanks to @ovs and @att!

Comment: That was hell of an optimization.

Comment: Sure it can be more golfed

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pzg1JzW5xC2zqLgkOigxLz01Os9WOVZHWTukyMEzryQ1PbXIJTM9s6TYQdnWNk8tVu1/QFFmXkl0moK@gwJYg4OxgUHsfwA) with `Range[n=#]` and `Tr` instead of `Total`.

Comment: `Cases` variants typically are shorter than `Select` variants when you need the outer argument in the selection function, but here `Pick` does better still: [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X1nNwSEgMzk7usg2KDEvPdVBWadIO6RI38EzryQ1PbXIJTM9s6TYoUhHOVbtv39aWrRbaV5ySWZ@npVVcU5@SV4sV0BRZl5JdJqCvoMCxARjA4PY/wA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io),  <s>40</s>  35 bytes

```arturo
$->x[0while[x<>+∑digits<=<=]->1+]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?zkCRSL)

Causes an infinite loop when there is no result.

```
$->x[                  ; a function taking an integer x
    0                  ; push 0 to stack
    while[x<>          ; while x doesn't equal...
        <=<=           ; duplicate top of stack twice
        +∑digits       ; digit sum then add
    ]                  ; end while condition
    ->1+               ; increment top of stack (while body)
]                      ; end function
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 49 bytes

Loops forever, in theory, if there's no result but, in practice, throws a recursion error.

```javascript
n=>(g=x=>n-eval([x,...x+``].join`+`)?g(++x):x)`0`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADA7@xiSnSqQHtIBCuRooSJieypr9tMtM2@Zwm5yjZ3p3vSBrxmbZK8mr1h50EpxYLoUPEJiQTh5kF@jCsjjdRzCamCg2lB7D8)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>45</s> 46 bytes

*Edit: +1 byte to correctly handle input of zero, but then -1 byte thanks pajonk for removal of useless accidental space*

```r
\(n){while(n-F-sum(F%/%10^(0:F)%%10))F=F+1;+F}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHSnJTEdNulpSVpuhY39WI08jSryzMyc1I18nTddItLczXcVPVVDQ3iNAys3DRVgSxNTTdbN21Da223Wqguc5ARGkaWmlwQhqEZlGUApY01FZQV8vIVivNzSksy8_MUUisyi0uKIdoXLIDQAA)

Tests increasing integers until it finds a solution, so loops forever if no solution exists.

Comment: You have an extra space at the start of you code...

Comment: @pajonk - Ah, thanks v much for spotting that!

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
x|msajdT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v6ImtzgxKyXk/38jQzMA)

Returns `-1` for no result.

#### Explanation

```
x|msajdTdQQQ    # implicitly add dQQQ
                # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
  m      Q      # map lambda d over range(Q):
     jdT        #   list the digits of d
    a   d       #   append d to this list
   s            #   sum the list
 |        Q     # short circuiting or, does nothing unless the input is 0, then [] -> 0
x          Q    # find the first index of Q in the mapped list (or xors with 0 for 0), returns -1 if not found
```

Comment: Input `0` also yields `-1`, which is untrue (should have been `0`). I apologize if this might cause non-alphabetical issues.

Comment: @TomEpsilon My bad, did not realize I needed to account for 0. And indeed it has :( but even worse it cost me a byte :(((

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 34 bytes

```
{first 0..$^n: {$_+.comb.sum==$n}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Oi2zqLhEwUBPTyUuz0qhWiVeWy85PzdJr7g019ZWJa@29n9xYqWCBlCBkYGmnZ2eWtp/AA)

Returns the `first` element of the range `0` through the input number `$^n`/`$n` such that the element `$_` plus the sum of its digits `.comb.sum` is equal to the input number.  If there is no such number, `Nil` is returned.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), <s>42</s> 37 bytes

```
~n=argmax(x->x+sum(digits(x))==n,0:n)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjdV6_JsE4vScxMrNCp07Sq0i0tzNVIy0zNLijUqNDVtbfN0DKzyNKGKg5UVXCsScwtyUq24HIoz8ssV6owMzbi4lBVCUotLirkcEouLU4tKFOoMFBRsbRUMEAJGliABQ0uEiLEBSMTIBGI0zD0A)

-5 bytes thanks to MarcMush: use `argmax` instead of `findfirst`

Comment: Your TIO doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I added an example that prints. Before, I had only been using `@assert` statements, which will silently pass if the tests succeed.

Comment: with `argmax`, [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7PNrEoPTexQsPAKk@vxq5C165Cu7g0VyMlMz2zpFijQlPT1jZPU9fwv7KCa0VibkFOqhWXQ3FGfrlCnZGhGReXskJIanFJMZdDYnFxalGJQp2BgoKtrYIBQsDIEiRgaIkQMTYAiRiZ/AcA) or [37 bytes with julia 1.7+](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjdV6_JsE4vScxMrNCp07Sq0i0tzNVIy0zNLijUqNDVtbfN0DKzyNKGKg5UVXCsScwtyUq24HIoz8ssV6owMzbi4lBVCUotLirkcEouLU4tKFOoMFBRsbRUMEAJGliABQ0uEiLEBSMTIBGI0zD0A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), <strike>74</strike> 72 bytes

```
import Enum
c=& &1-?0
r=&find(1..&1,fn x->&1==x+sum map'#{x}',c end)||-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZctBC4IwGIDhu7/iY8HcaA4/QcFgderQqZ8QphMGbslUGGS/fdUt6fw@rx5MMD5GY8eHn@HsFpu0igLF7JQnXtHeuI6hlBRF7yBkR4pKhf20WLDNmO6e4ZWKFrTr@LpmGC9Xadw06nZmn/49y1yA5wKG5q6HA5Dm5ghPfpyXrKg3oKj/BVZbghXh8Q0)

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 85 bytes

```java
n->{for(int i=-1;i++<n;)if((i+"").chars().map(d->d-48).sum()+i==n)return i;return-1;}
```

Outputs `-1` if there is no result.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PZAxb4MwEIX3/IoTky2MVWiVQihZOjdLxjSDa0zrFA5km1RVxG@nNkkq@U728@l9T3cSZ5Gc6u9ZtsJaeBMaLysAjU6ZRkgFu/BcBJAkdKSlV6aVb9YJpyXsAKGaMdlemt4sM7pK0lLH8QuWVDeE6DiKKJdfwlhCeScGUifbOnnKKbdjR2isqwqpUW40CLq8XrzFNJeBM4wfrefccOde19D5oGTvjMbPw1HQa8g73inrXoVVG1Q/IfnheMkKlqVr9sDScHxlj6zIn9csZf4naDlLi3yiixHA/tc61fF@dHzwENciubvG0ebdRTFy@S/R206m@Q8)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                   // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  for(int i=-1;i++<n;) //  Loop `i` in the range (-1,n]:
    if((i+"")          //   Convert `i` to a String
       .chars()        //   Then to an IntStream of codepoints
       .map(d->d-48)   //   Then to an IntStream of digits
       .sum()          //   And sum those digits together
             +i        //   Add integer `i`
               ==n)    //   And if it's equal to input `n`:
      return i;        //    Return `i` as result
  return-1;}           //  If no result is found, return `-1` instead
```

Using a recursive function which throws a `StackOverflowError` when there is no result is also **85 bytes**:

```java
n->f(n,0)int f(int n,int i){return(i+"").chars().map(d->d-48).sum()+i==n?i:f(n,i+1);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZHPb8IgFMfv/hUvPUFKG@uMqza6w7Kj7uBlifPAKJ1oCw1QjWn6r6@Duh@HXUbgAe/B@3x5HOmZRsf81LOSGgNrKmQ7AhDScl1QxmHjt4MDGPJW4sx5upEzG5Cw7GW0KpAkY5z5cHE7RLwVuNXcNloiEQYBjtmBaoNwXNEa5dEqj6Ypjk1TIRyK5VI@iIVPJMIEZ12feULdvJWCgbHUuumsRA6Vk4i2Vgv5vttTfJNXKD1wLTf2kRq@kPziNe/27WROJsmMjEniuxuTOzJP72ckIS7ifSlJ5mmHh0QAVl/bryXA9mosr2LV2Lh2RFtK9I0Ig8WrDUIP8lVzz5Ix@4nioUq@dYxadnCKKTs9n11VS3V50lpp4Br/n/T3fvCLGD6k6z9UbYWSpo9ejJmuPwE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
ＮθＩ⌊Φ⊕θ⁼θ⁺ιΣι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDObG4RMM3My8ztzRXwy0zpwQo65mXXJSam5pXkpoCVKmj4FpYmphTrFGooxCQU1qskamjEAxUnKkJAdb//xsZmv3XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes `i` as an input and outputs `None` if no generator exists. Explanation: Brute force approach.

```
Ｎθ              First input as an integer
      θ         First input
     ⊕          Incremented
    Φ           Filter on implicit range
          ι     Current value
         ⁺      Plus
            ι   Current value
           Σ    Digit sum
       ⁼        Equals
        θ       First input
   ⌊            Take the minimum
  Ｉ             Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

23 bytes for a less inefficient version:

```
ＮθＩ⌊Φ…·⁻θ×⁹Ｌθθ⁼θ⁺ιΣ⌈⟦⁰ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzLCsIwFET3fkWWNxDBumiQLkWhYKWoO3FxLaG9kETzKv59jMWBWZ2ZM0zohxfqnFv7TvGczFN5cLxZ9Z5shD2GCB1ZMsnAkXQstLWDToFmdUE7qh9NAZxgNzIqwE6wk7JjnIqFc8Fc6cEl1MumL08gwa5F1@Fn0d43gtGD/9PkXNVSym1V5/Wsvw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Starts checking for generators starting from `i` minus `9` times the number of digits of `i`.

28 bytes for a more efficient version:

```
ＮθＩ⌊ΦＥＬθ⁻⁻θ﹪×⁵θ⁹×⁹ι⁼θ⁺ιΣ⌈⟦⁰ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NasMwEITvfQofZXBgV1r9kWNooVCXQHsrPaiJSQSyHdtSyNurcpI9DMzOfMzh7ObD6ELO78Mlxc/U/3Uzm@rty372Q2Q7t0TW@sH3qWdvPsSStu7CPrrhFM@l2FQlTQt76FTseExhZN@@7xYmm2qt2LrI42ObyterfZ2SC3diHwrpm@qrTLTudp/6gdL7rZ@3zdmgkchJcUmouSCSIKTkGoG4skIDCa0ASmSUEVoaIrCkLFhQWiOalbIoyApURnLkqPLmGv4B) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: As above, but only checks for generators which when doubled are equivalent to `i` modulo `9` (because `i` equals the generator plus its digit sum but both the generator and the digit sum are equivalent modulo `9`) although it actually computes the maximum possible generator by subtracting `5i` reduced modulo `9` from `i`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>73</strike> 72 bytes

```cs
n=>{for(int i=-1;i++<n;)if((i+"").Sum(d=>d-'0')+i==n)return i;return-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVA9a8MwEJ2tX3FkiYQ/iFNobRx7CbRLC4UMHUoHVZbTA1tqJTmlGP929xIylA56evfupHd3yqfKOr2MHs0RDj8@6KFif6PsEc3XP2lv@16rgNb47EEb7VBVjH2O7z0qUL30Hp6dPTo5sIlFV90HGeg6WWzhSaLhgkWUje5Ho3ZoQgIEDXRQL6Zups46TgJgneYVxvHOVAI7zjFerUR2GAfe1k2brjdrEWNdG@F0GJ0BrK6Ens1LRQb0k5bqA/hJOkByAaO/z2avb9O2TGCb3yawSSC/nDNsbxIoizuScyJUcckUBGUxU9tRtKfRba@zF4dB04Y07zgKQXYzm5df)

This is a C# port of this [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/261861/lowest-digit-addition-generator/261871#261871). All the kudos goes to Kevin Cruijssen.

I really like that .NET's `sum` is taking a lambda to avoid the common map followed by sum!

Comment: You can remove the space at `return-1;` like in my Java answer for -1 byte. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen forgot this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes

```python
g=lambda n:min(x for x in range(n)if x+sum(map(int,str(x)))==n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoAgDAXQq3Rso5NOmnCYGhWbyIcAJnh69I0vvfWKmHv37taw7UpYg4EbnTFTIwNlhT8YYie1oTyBgyY21LHUzE1EnIP0lP9iz9Mi0j8)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 56 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,o=0:(o+sum(map(int,str(o)))==n)*o or f(n,o+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcpBCoAgEAXQfadwOT9dZEFQ4GGMkIJ0RG3R6adWLR@8/LSD0yQS3OXjtnuVDLthJdb1jhR9pjM1U1shBuBcQs@Kiwr0RW0huXyBAo12BrpfCyAv)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: `o*(...)or f(...` saves a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$11\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 9.054 bytes

```
[KFax'=#x+S
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJbS0ZheCc9I3grUyIsIjIxNiJd)

```
[            # The first item from
   a         # the range from 1 to
    x        # the input,
  F  '       # filtered by:
          S  #   the digit sum of n
         +   #   plus n
      =      #   is equal to
       #x    #   the program's input,
 K           # sorted (smallest to largest).
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, <s>84</s>  80 bytes

```swift
{n in(0...n).map{($0,"\($0)".reduce($0){$0+$1.hexDigitValue!})}.first{$1==n}!.0}
```

Takes an `Int` in and returns an `Int`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcaxCsIwEIDhV7mWDDnUIxUXhTi5@AJOLkUTPWiPkl5RCHn2WJf/@@cPRz3UISjEE9irKMLuDKvgaxZgsY6IBGnsp2yN27b3tdhSCs/lEf6fjduYjt7he@EX660fltAULBQ5zZpN572UhlypU2JRG@3@iFh/)

Ungolfed:

```swift
{ (n: Int) -> Int in
  (0...n) // a sequence of all integers from 0 to n, inclusive
    // the parens are needed to avoid parsing as 0...(n.map)
    .map { i in // transform each one
      ( // return a tuple of:
        i, // 0. the integer itself
        "\(i)".reduce(i) { $0 + $1.hexDigitValue! } // 1. the digit sum plus the number
        // technically, wholeNumberValue would be more correct than hexDigitValue
      )
    }
    .first { $1 == n }! // find the first one where the sum is the input
    .0 // and return the number that gave that sum
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=sum -pa`, 29 bytes

```perl
$_=0;$_++while"@F"-sum$_,/./g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbAWiVeW7s8IzMnVcnBTUm3uDRXJV5HX08//f9/I8t/@QUlmfl5xf91fX0yi0usrEJLMnNsgWqAAqZ6BoYG/3ULEgE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 66 bytes

```
I=[0...n]
f(n)=I[[i+∑_{k=0}^imod(floor(i/10^k),10)fori=I]=n].min
```

Returns `undefined` if no solution exists.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9esxyqdldh)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qz6ogtumcb)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 46 bytes

```ruby
1.step{|c|p (1..c).find{|x|x+x.digits.sum==c}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31CvuCS1oLomuaZAQcNQTy9ZUy8tMy@luqaipkK7Qi8lMz2zpFivuDTX1ja5tvb/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `M`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
æDS+=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kq9S7IKlpSVpuhbLDi9zCda2XVKclFwMFVqwyMgSwgIA)

##### Explanation

```python
æDS+=  # Implicit input
æ      # Filter [1..input] by:
 D     #  Duplicate
  S    #  Sum digits
   +   #  Add
    =  #  Equals input?
       # Take the minimum
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 52 bytes

```haskell
a n=find((==n).ap(+)(sum.map digitToInt.show))[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BSwQxDIXv@RU5eGgRizugMgvjZb0I7klv4iHa7k7YNh3aLOKvHzvDXjYQeO8j72WkegoxzjOnKRfFXRYtObp9FvJwgS@k5HYjlSvwxlWvwJ7@vgNAIhYc0GfANjEolkD@VbTBReF2i@9aWI5494yNr3csGgr9KN7gWSJLqOgw0YSmjvm36UPJaf2A981R20utbXINABDKcGDxxgyDWEeTubWmnpNbijwfWT9yS7il0trPjXPyNc9dD93mEbqnB@j6/h8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 71 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BS8NAEIXv/RVD6WEX06WJoElwC6IePIgH8aQiY7oJI8mm7I6ClPz2OE2tujCP5c2bbyZW2OLYv727iuEOycNuBvI@sYWqvPVs1yJgR2/XagXcg9emJr9RJAYZ7h84kG9Mh1v1ajBeU0OsTfzoTkhbK@nG8X24aaNTy1SPQt@4GjpZpTA0sYTLEPDr6YB50SU8epKF/@5gF/kKo4viTmGVFQlk6VkCqwTSqfaSnSZQ5Odip/KRxNTJRYpcT7S6D6COOLhY/qH1zz6ArdzBrVdxvjh2y2de7KrfQT3MD7hhtq9h/AY)

```scala
n=>(0 to n).find(i=>(i.toString.map(_.asDigit).sum+i)==n).getOrElse(-1)
```